# Adding days to monthly events in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMETER $$
CREATE EVENT loan_balance ON SCHEDULE EVERY  '1' MONTH AND '5' DAYS 
DO BEGIN UPDATE users SET loan_balance = total_loans_collected - 
total_loans_paid;
END$$
DELIMETER;
```

Hello! I want to update this table on the 5th of every month and not just monthly. The "AND '5' DAYS isn't making it work.

Comment: Why do you need this code exactly?  You could just make a generated column or a view for this.

Comment: 5th of every month is the date deductions are usually made.

Answer (score 1):

You need a slightly different [`ON SCHEDULE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) phrase.

```
 AT '2018-04-01 03:01' + INTERVAL 5 DAY EVERY MONTH
```

fires your event at 03:01 local time on the fifth day of every month.

`03:01` is a good time for a scheduled job because it doesn't get messed up by standard-time / daylight-time switchovers.

Comment: Very close to what I want, but it displays syntax error near EVERY MONTH. Any adjustments?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a trigger to update the `loan_balance` column, you can turn it into a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html).

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY COLUMN loan_balance INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS
(total_loans_collected - total_loans_paid) STORED;
```

Unless I'm missing something, I believe this is the most optimal approach, and it is certainly easier to maintain.